# Why do INSERT and DELETE screw up QTableView (Qt, C++, sqlite)?

Tags: c++, sql, qt, qt4, pyqt

After setting an INSERT or DELETE query on `QSqlQueryModel`, my `QTableView` becomes screwed up. For example I hid the ID column by calling `view->hideColumn(ID);` but after an INSERT or DELETE the ID column becomes visible.

How can I automatically reset my view to the previous settings in these cases?

Comment: post up some of your code, snippets where you're initializing models and views will be helpful.

Comment: The whole code is available here, revision 1751: http://szte-wsn.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/szte-wsn/private/ali/SQL/SQLDialog/SQLDialog.cpp?view=log The weird thing is this: SELECT does not mess up my view, only INSERT and DELETE do. I guess they trigger something resetting the previous settings of the view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the problem is in [QSqlQueryModel::setQuery](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsqlquerymodel.html#setQuery) you're eventually calling every time content gets reloaded and rows inserts\deletes. Looking at the setQuery implementation I would suggest: depending on the query your model can be reset including columns settings change which should trigger view columns update.

As Qt documentation suggests:

> The QSqlQueryModel class provides a
>   read-only data model for SQL result
>   sets.

so I would use direct [QSqlQuery](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsqlquery.html) calls for the data updates and then would reload the model with the same query. Or consider switching to [QSQLTableModel](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsqltablemodel.html), which is quite handy for single table content manipulation and supports inserts updates and deletes. See if an example below would work for you:

set up database, view and model:

```
QSqlTableModel *_model;
QTableView *_view;
```

...

```
QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
db.setDatabaseName(":memory:");
db.open() ;

QSqlQuery query;
query.prepare("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (id INTEGER UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(30))");
query.exec();
query.prepare("INSERT INTO person (name) VALUES ('test1')");
query.exec();
query.prepare("INSERT INTO person (name) VALUES ('test2')");
query.exec();

_model = new QSqlTableModel(this, db);
_model->setTable("person");
_model->setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);
_model->select();
_model->setHeaderData(1, Qt::Horizontal, tr("name"));
_model->setSort(1, Qt::AscendingOrder);

_view = new QTableView(this);
_view->setModel(_model);
_view->hideColumn(0);
```

add new row:

```
QSqlRecord record;
_model->insertRecord(-1, record);
```

delete selected row(s):

```
QModelIndexList selected = _view->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes();
for (int i = 0; i < selected.size(); ++i)
    _model->removeRows(selected.at(i).row(), 1);
```

submit changes:

```
_model->submitAll();
```

hope this helps, regards

Comment: At the moment direct QSqlQuery calls seem to be the best choice for the problem at hand. Many thanks for the help!